# Could you explain me one thing about synchronization in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

Imagine that we have multithreading application and a class with the following variable and method:

```
private List list = new ArrayList();
public void doNothing() {
    synchronized (list) {
        list.get(0);
        String stuff = "Stuff";
        list.get(0);
    }
}
```

Am I right that when one thread processes method `doNothing()` it loses monitor on `String stuff = "Stuff";` and the output of `list.get(0);` may be different because other thread can modify the list?

Comment: `stuff` is not monitored in your example, and `list.get(0)` may or may not return a different value depending on whether or not the modifier synchronizes on the list when updating.

Comment: First of all, it depends on what, if any, locking the other threads are doing.

Comment: No. The monitor on list is held until the end of the synchronized block.

Comment: ...and what does `String stuff` have to do with the rest of the code? The connection is really not clear.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are right, but not because the monitor is lost on handling the stuff string. The fact that you synchronized on the list does not prevent another thread to change it. The only way to enforce the list being unchanged between the two gets is to have all threads changing the list run that code inside a synchronized(list). Also, having a [Synchronized list](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedList(java.util.List)) will not help in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Only one thread at a time can work in *synchronized* block. But if any other thread modifies the list in for example some other function then of course, output of list.get(0) can differ between invocations. String stuff due to being created in this block can't be changed by any other thread than the one that is currently running through it.

Answer (score 0):

Only one thread can execute inside a Java code block synchronized on the same monitor object.

The thread only "loses the monitor" once it reaches the end of the synchronized block.

In your specific case, the result from calling list.get(0); can be the same or not, depending on other threads that can invoke the mutators on that list outside any code block synchronized on the list object.

The purpose of the synchronization objects is to allow you to synchronize more than one block on the same lock.

In the following example only one thread can execute inside any of the two blocks at the same time:

```
public void doNothing() {
    synchronized (list) {
        //someStuff
    }
}

public void doSomething() {
    synchronized (list) {
        //anotherStuff
    }
}
```

Comment: But if I write synchronized(list) does it mean that only 1 thread in the whole application has an access to this list or not?

Comment: No. It means that only one thread can execute inside any block synchronized on the "list" object.

If you have many code blocks that access the same sensitive data, you can synchronize all that blocks on the same object, granting that only one thread can execute inside any of them at the same time

Comment: I edited my answer to address the purpose of the synchronization objects

Comment: so if these 2 methods are in different classes that means that while a certain thread executing doNothing() other thread cannot execute doSomething?

Comment: Yes, that's what it means... As long as they are synchronized at the exact same object, only one thread can execute any of them at the same time.

Comment: If your need is to be sure that no modifications can occur to your list while some thread is execution you block, you should use a synchronized List (wich uses synchronization on a given object to archive that) ... If you want i can edit my answer to show an example.